# Extending a Ramsey filter

Tags: set-theory, ultrafilters

We take filter to mean filter on $\omega$ containing all cofinite sets.  We say a filter $F$ is Ramsey if ZERO does not have a winning strategy in the following infinite game between the two players ZERO and PLUS.  ZERO starts by choosing $A_0 = \omega$, and then PLUS  chooses $k_0\in \omega$. In the move number $j+1$, by induction $A_j\in F$ and  ZERO chooses $A_{j+1}\subseteq A_j$ with $A_{j+1}\in F$, then PLUS chooses $k_{j+1}\in A_{j+1}$.  PLUS wins if $\{k_j: j\in \omega\}\in F$, otherwise ZERO wins.

Now suppose that $F$ is a Ramsey filter (though perhaps not ultra). If $\langle S_n : n<\omega\rangle$ is a $\subseteq^*$-decreasing sequence such that $\forall n [(\omega \setminus S_n)\not\in F]$.

**Question:**  Is there a set $S$ with $S\subseteq^* S_n$ for all $n$ and $(\omega\setminus S)\not\in F$

Note that this definition of Ramsey is not totally standard, but I need an internal definition for Ramsey; i.e. one that only refers to sets in $F$. I would be interested in other possible internal definitions of Ramsey that would imply the existence of such an $S$.

**Remark** (explanation of title):  This is part of a construction I am trying to use to extend a Ramsey filter to a Ramsey ultrafilter. I would be interested also in other ways to do this.

**More Background** It's easy to find $S$ with $S\subseteq^*S_n$for all $n$. Also if $F$ is only countable then (I think) we can proceed as follows.  First find $S^*\in F$ with $S^*\subseteq^* A$ for every $A\in F$ (use the game).  Now note that $\omega \setminus (S_n\cap S^*) \not\in F$ for all $n$ (since otherwise $\omega\setminus S_n\in F$). So define $S'_n = S_n\cap S^*.$ We can find an infinite $S$ such that $S\subseteq^*S'_n$ for every $n$. We claim that $S$ is as desired; In fact suppose that $(\omega\setminus S)\in F$. But $S\subseteq^*S^*\subseteq A$ for every $A\in F$. So $S\subseteq^*(\omega\setminus S)$, a contradiction that $S$ is infinite.

Comment: You may find the answer in Laflamme's survey: 
MR1367134: Filter games and combinatorial properties of strategies. Set theory (Boise, ID, 1992–1994), 51–67,
Contemp. Math., 192, AMS. (1996)